# Medion Akoya E2212T (MD 99720): after reinstall Windows 10 32bit no mouse / no keyboard (and no sound which was also missing before)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, mouse, sound-card

I have reinstalled Windows 10 32bit on my old netbook Medion Akoya E2212T (MD 99720) in order to get my sound back which I was missing since an update in 2017. The only solution since then was to reinstall Windows as a whole, which seemed too much work for me up to now.

Many years later, after a fresh install, instead of getting the sound back, I was even missing the mouse and the keyboard as well as the sound. The pure tablet touch screen was working well, but the base part of the netbook was not working anymore, no USB either so that I could not add an external keyboard / mouse.

How to get these devices (keyboard, mouse, sound)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to device-manager in the Windows menu:

- Mice and other pointing drivers

  - Double-click the mice that have a tiny yellow triangle with an exclamation mark (They have the wrong driver "Pluralinput Mouse 1.0").
  - Go to tab "Driver".
  - Choose "update driver".
  - Take the second option "search on my computer for drivers"
  - Click on the bottom blue text with the arrow to the right "Choose from a list of drivers available on my computer".
  - Double-click **"HID-conform" mouse**.
- Keyboards

  - Same as with mice, just choose **HID-keyboard** here. (They have the wrong driver "Pluralinput Keyboard 1.0".)
- System devices --> Sound

  - Double-click the tiny yellow triangle with the exclamation mark rather in the middle of the list called "Intel(R) Atom(TM)/Celeron(R)/Pentium(R) Processor Low Power Engine Audio - Host Bridge - 0F28".
  - Go to tab "Driver".
  - Check whether you can do the same steps as before, in my case, it was not possible to find another driver than already installed.
  - I found the download by the following links

    - [Fix Atom Z3735F no sound after Windows 10 update](https://medium.com/@maxpower0203/fix-atom-z3735f-no-sound-after-windows-10-update-636e4ff125d5) (*thanks go to the author of this blog, please add a clap if you find the time*) -->
    - Get to the detailed drivers of your choice [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/86612/Intel-Compute-Stick-STCK1A32WFC)
    - Then [this is the direct download of the driver for Windows 10](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25311/eng/SOC_BYT_Win10_32.zip).
  - Unzip
  - Again: Double-click the tiny yellow triangle with the exclamation mark rather in the middle of the list called "Intel(R) Atom(TM)/Celeron(R)/Pentium(R) Processor Low Power Engine Audio - Host Bridge - 0F28".
  - Again: Go to tab "Driver".
  - If you now take the uppert option and search for the driver on your own, choose the **"SOC_BYT_Win10_32"** folder that you have unzipped and go on, you see the successful installation of **"Intel SST Audio Device (WDM)"**.
- Optional: *Update the rest of Intel drivers:*

  - *At this point, you might also consider downloading the [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_IDSA), in my case I found that there was a more current "Intel HD Graphics Driver for STCK1A32WFC" that was not found by the Windows update). With some luck this fixes the often "stopping touchpad mouse" (out of the middle of nowhere) which I can then only get back when I take off the tablet and put it on again. That was not the question here, but should still be mentioned.*

You have to choose the mouse / keyboard driver whenever you add a new device, even if it is just a remote mouse / keyboard. In my first tests, adding a mouse even stopped the touchpad again, and everything worked again when I chose the right drivers for *every* device of the added device type (that is, the whole group of existing mice for example) again.